# How can I transfer files from a Windows 7 host to a Windows 8 guest in Virtualbox without internet?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-8.1, shared-folders

I have a Windows 8.1 dev preview running with VirtualBox on a Windows 7 machine.  The virtual machine has it's virtual network interface cable "unplugged" so it's never been online.  I've installed the VirtualBox guest additions with no issues in order to use the Shared Folders option.

After installation and setting up the network folders, everything appears fine when viewing "This PC" as the networked folder shows up and can be opened and everything in the networked folder can be viewed.  All sub folders can be opened and their contents viewed with no issues.

However, when trying to open any of these files, a message comes up saying "Open this file and make it available offline?  You recently opened this file and we still have a temporary copy.  Choose 'Make available offline' to open this copy and make it always available when you're not connected to the Internet" with two options, "Make available offline" and "Cancel".  When clicking "Cancel", the message closes and it returns you to the window you were viewing (as expected).  When clicking "Make available offline" the message closes and it returns you to the window you were viewing as if you clicked cancel instead of opening the file.

If I try to copy the file from the networked folder to the desktop, I receive a different message: "[Filename] is only available when you are connected to the internet.  Connect to the internet and try again." with the options to  "Try Again", "Skip", and "Cancel".  If I click "Try Again", the file copy dialog window pops up for a moment, staying at 0%, then returning to the same error message with the three options.  If i click "Skip", the file copy dialog window pops up, this time appearing as if to actually copy the file as the bar moves across the window and the percentage increases from 0% to 100% as if actually copying the file but the window closes after it reaches 100% and no file is on my desktop.

Attempting the same in a Windows XP guest on virtual box with no virtual network cabled "attached" causes no issues and I can easily access all networked folders with no problem.

I have not tried with a Windows Vista or Windows 7 guest.

It appears to be a Windows 8 issue rather than a VirtualBox issue but if anyone knows any work around that'd be great!

Comment: As a public service I will make this comment.  You really should get off the Developer Preview because it is set to expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CD burning software to create an iso disc image with the files you want and attach the disc image to the guest OS.

Comment: Thanks! Totally forgot about this.  Now just to figure out how to make Windows 8 actually access the shared folders.

Answer (score 0):

Install VirtualBox Guest Additions ([link for 2.2](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/2.2.0/VBoxGuestAdditions_2.2.0.iso))

And then add the source folder on the host as a shared folder on the Virtual Machine (see manual [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)).

Navigate to the shared folder and copy the file from the shared folder to the guest, or open it from the shared folder. Your choice.

Comment: Thanks but the Guest Additions are already installed and the shared folder is already hosted.  I can access the folder and subfolders in the virtual machine but Windows 8 seems to be preventing me from actually accessing the files due to there being no internet connection.

Comment: Why can't you install/enable the virtual network adapter?

Comment: I just have it set so the virtual cable is "not connected" in VirtualBox's network settings for that VM.  It's not that I can't, it's just the whole point of running the VM is to keep it isolated.  The networked folders appear to work in Win8 by still showing up and being accessible to view the file list and all sub folders, but none of the actual files are accessible because Windows 8 wants me to be "connected to the internet".

Comment: That's probably why it can't grab from the shared folders correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to use USB Flash Memory:

1- Connect your USB Flash Memory to your computer.

2- Your flash memory should get recognized for your virtual machine in:

Setting > USB > Add new USB

3- Run your VB machine and go to removable drive as usual and explore your files.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please be aware you have posted an answer to a question that is very old and has an accepted answer. Although there is nothing wrong with doing so, just be aware you may not get a response.